# conditional compliation based on variable into makefile

Tags: include, makefile, conditional-compilation

Inside my C/C++ code I would like to include or not a file depending on different compilation.

For the moment I use this:

```
#ifndef __x86_64__
    #include <myLib.h>
#endif
```

this gives me the possibility of doing whether the platform is 32/64 bit but does not give me enough freedom.

I would like to pass a variable to my makefile like

```
make includeMyLib=1
```

and depending on this having something like:

```
#ifndef includeMyLib
    #include <myLib.h>
#endif
```

Do you know if anything like this is possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use GNU make, you could have something like this in the `Makefile`:

```
ifdef includeMyLib
CFLAGS += -DincludeMyLib
endif
```

This will change the flags used by the compiler to add the `#define` `includeMyLib`.