# #ifdef and conditional compilation with Makefile

Tags: c, makefile, compilation, gnu-make

Prior to asking I had saw this, tried but didn't help :
[conditional compliation based on variable into makefile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10103006/conditional-compliation-based-on-variable-into-makefile)

In my case my `src_file.c` contains:

```
#ifndef WITH_ATS
#define WITH_ATS
#include "ats.h"
#endif
```

And Makefile has:

```
ifdef WITH_ATS
INCLUDEDIR += -I../at2_build/include/
LDFLAGS += -L$(AT2) -lat2 -Wl,-rpath=$(AT2)
CFLAGS += -DWITH_ATS
endif
```

What I am trying is, if I do `make WITH_ATS=1` file should compile with compiled `ats` lib,
whereas if do `make WITH_ATS=0` compilation should be without `ats` lib.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Don't use conditional compilation in `Makefile` but only in C source files. You might generate dependencies for `make` but that is a very different question.

Comment: I know this isn't what you're asking, but rather than using GNU make's `ifdef`, consider using portable Makefile constructs and idioms, as explained in [A tutorial on portable Makefiles](http://nullprogram.com/blog/2017/08/20/)

Comment: This is not a complete question. What is it that is not working for you?

Comment: @imhotap Thanks for the tutorial. It will be a great help for me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Makefile

The variable `WITH_ATS` is [not empty](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Conditional-Syntax.html) when running `make WITH_ATS=0`, and therefore `ifdef WITH_ATS` in the makefile evaluates to true (i.e., not what you expect).

What you actually need is to check whether `WITH_ATS` is equal to `1`. This can be achieved by means of `ifeq`:

```
ifeq ($(WITH_ATS),1)
INCLUDEDIR += -I../at2_build/include/
LDFLAGS += -L$(AT2) -lat2 -Wl,-rpath=$(AT2)
CFLAGS += -DWITH_ATS
endif
```

---

#### C source file

In your `src_file.c` you need neither `#ifndef` nor `#define`. What you are implementing that way is an [*include guard*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard), which is not what you want, what you actually need is:

```
#ifdef WITH_ATS
#include "ats.h"
#endif
```

That is, to include `ats.h` if `WITH_ATS` is defined.

Note that, in your C source file, `WITH_ATS` is just an empty macro (i.e., it doesn't have any value associated), whereas in your makefile, `WITH_ATS` is a variable that takes the value passed at the command line, e.g., `0` for `make WITH_ATS=0`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `if` instead of `ifdef`.

```
#if WITH_ATS
#include "ats.h"
#endif
```